# "Partículas" se movendo com o mouse no background

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho quadradinhos de quatro cores e gostaria de jogar eles no background de forma aleatória e dar aquele efeito de parallax quando mexe o mouse. Alguém conhece algum plugin pra isso?

Estilo isso, mas colocando os quadrados no lugar dos pontos. http://jnicol.github.io/particleground/

Obrigado.

Comment: Sua pergunta tem 4 votos para fechar como ampla demais. Eu quase dei o quinto voto que a fecharia, mas pensando com calma e lendo o texto da questão com atenção, achei melhor dar uma resposta mesmo. Na minha opinião, esta pergunta apenas está escrita de uma forma que parece ser ampla demais mas não é.

Answer (score 1):

Olhando o código da biblioteca que você linkou (basta clicar no botão "download"), encontramos isso:

```js
    /**
     * Draw particle
     */
    Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
      // Draw circle
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX, this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY, options.particleRadius / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
```

Vou modificar para desenhar um quadrado:

```
    /**
     * Draw particle
     */
    Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
      // Draw square
      var ix = this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX;
      var iy = this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY;
      ctx.fillRect(ix - options.particleRadius / 2, iy - options.particleRadius / 2, options.particleRadius, options.particleRadius);
```

Testei a modificação acima com o código do demo que está junto com a biblioteca (que é o código do site) e funcionou perfeitamente. :)

Só tenho que avisar que o `options.particleRadius` tem um nome enganador. Não sei por qual motivo, isso na verdade não é o raio da partícula, e sim o diâmetro.

Para mudar a cor, basta acrescentar algo assim antes do `fillRect`:

```
var oldStyle = ctx.fillStyle;
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000'; // Use a cor que preferir aqui.
```

E isso depois:

```
ctx.fillStyle = oldStyle;
```

Comment: Eu acho também que a pergunta não é ampla, boa resposta +1